# Send variable from one component to another in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a routing where the component ProductId will be rendered (a href="/id")when there is a click on div with class name="card"

```html
<a href="/id">
    <div className="card">
      <div className="imgBx">
        <h1>Product</h1>
        <img src={image} alt={image} className="myProductImage" />
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="productName">
          <h3>{name}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="price_rating">
          <div className="price">{price} $</div>
          <div className="ratings">
              {ratings}
            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
    </a>
```

The Route is defined as following:

```html
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/id" component={ProductId}/>
         <Route path="/" exact component={Products}/> 
     </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById("root")
   );
```

Now when the component ProductId is rendered I want to pass props (_id), (this props is present in the component where the onClick event is taking place) with onClick but since I am not calling the  directly I cannot pass the props like .

Is there any other way where I can pass the props to the ProductId component when there is an onClick event on div with class name="card"

Comment: By chance, are you aware of [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)?

Comment: Check out React Context

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you should use a dynamic route that contain the product `id`

For example :

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductId} />
</Router>
```

Then your `ProductId` component will receive the `id` from the router params in `props.match.params.id`

see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component